# Can multiple RocksDB instances exceed the system's max_open_files value?

Tags: ubuntu, ulimit, rocksdb

If a system's `ulimit max_open_files` is set to 1024 and there are 10 RocksDB instances running with `max_open_files = 256`, is it possible that RocksDB will exceed the system's ulimit? 
Should I configure each RocksDB instance with no more than 1/10th of the system's ulimit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system's `ulimit` is a per process parameter. Assuming you are running 10 RocksDB instances in separate process, each with `max_open_files = 256`. This will not exceed the system's ulimit. The current setting should just work fine.

Comment: This answer is corroborated here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75996/modify-ulimit-open-files-of-a-specific-process